What if there is only one measurement equation while there are two unobservable state variables in a state-space model?
I am learning Kalman Filter and ran into a question about the case in which only one signal is available.
It is commonly assumed that the number of states equals the number of observations (signals) in the measurement equation. For instance if there are two unobservable states, it is assumed that there are two independent signals. However, in reality, this assumption does not always hold. I am considering the following example:
States variables: $x_1$ and $x_2$ (say that they follow AR(1) process and each is independent of the other)
Observation equation (only one): $y_t = \alpha_1x_1 +\alpha_2x_2+\nu_{t}$ (where $\nu_t$ is a noise, normally distributed)
In this case, dimension of $Q$ (process noise covariance) is 2 by 2 while $R$ (signal noise covariance) is a scalar. Given this condition, how do I calculate Kalman Gain($K_t = PH^\prime(HPH^\prime+R)^{-1}$)? Can I just multipy $R$ by $I_2$ to match the dimensions of $Q$ and $R$?

Are you familiar with observability?

@KwinvanderVeen  Hi, I found my logical errors. Sorry my bad.
